# self processing php pages with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

re this post [AJAX Post to self in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290624/ajax-post-to-self-in-php)

When using exit() doesn't something have to be printed before this call?
I have written markup/ph with references to external css php scripts. The script uses print (or echo) and a 
call to header('type: text/css'). Isn't this useful or necessary in self processing php pages? I find
them endlessly useful. A whole site can be displayed in any state by one page using get queries and posts
from forms. I remember the text I was reading early on when beginning to learn php asserted that when
the page submits to itself, the browser will automatically use asynchronous requests. But in certain situations
an explicit ajax call is useful.

Comment: why do you think something would need to be printed?

Comment: How is the script going to send anything without it?

Comment: why would it need to send anything? HTTP POST operations are not required to generate any content at all.

Comment: Suppose I want to query a database on the server and have it send the results of the query? Anyhow I figured it out. I call header with string Content-Type: text/plain and then call print() and I have a test page with a text field and the server just echos it back to the page.

Comment: If... you... want to generate output, you generate output. You were asking whether something *had* to be generated. The answer is no. No output is *required*. It's certainly nice to the user, but there is no requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing and what I am trying to do. 
I have a text field and a button in a page
I write text to the text field and click the button
The javascript click event handler for the button gets the text field value
and appends it to a get query attached to the url in the request. The method is get

edit: to specify the environment in which this has been successful.
I am using Firefox v12.0 On Mac OSX with pre-installed apache server on local machine.
(anyone with a Mac running OSX, there is a pre installed apache server, but activating php requires
editing the httpd.com file to un comment the line(s) that load the php module. Also, there is a line
that tells Apache what extensions to use to look for and execute php code. You also must tell it
to take index.php as an index file to run the php in it and have it act as a directory index file)

the javascript code:

```
function _FETCH()
     { 
      this.init = function(oName, elem, txt)
           {
            var but = document.getElementById(elem);
                but.addEventListener('click', function(){ oName.req('GET', self, '', null, oName, txt) } )
           }

      this.req = function(method, url, type, msg, oName, txt)
           {
             var field = document.getElementById(txt);
                 url+="?ajxTst="+encodeURIComponent(field.value);
             var it = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 it.open(method, url, type);
                 it.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                 it.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {
                     var elem = document.getElementById('well');
                     switch(it.readyState)
                       {  
                        case 0:
                        case 1:
                        break;
                        case 2:
                        case 3:
                        elem.childNodes[0].data = " waiting";
                        break;
                        case 4:
                        oName.handleResponse(it.responseText);
                        break;
                        default:
                        alert('ajax processing error');
                        break;
                       }
                    }
                 it.send(msg);
           }

      this.handleResponse = function(resp)
           {
            var elem = document.getElementById('well');
                elem.childNodes[0].data = " "+resp;
           }
     }
```

The php, javascript and markup in the page:

```
<?php
/*
created 11/4/2014
*/
$_self = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if($_POST || $_GET)
  {
   if($_GET['ajxTst'])
     {
      header("Content-Type: text/plain");
      print $_GET['ajxTst'];
      exit();
     }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>JS lab 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="local.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="local.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
  var self = "<?php print $_self; ?>";
  window.onload = function()
   {
    var ajx = new _FETCH();
        ajx.init(ajx, 'send', 'tlk');
    }
 //]]>
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="panel">
 <p class="title">Js Lab 2</p>
 <p class="norm"><a href="../?uar=lab_3">Lab 3 home</a></p>
 <p class="norm">Work with ajax and self processing page (this)</p>
 <hr />
 <p class="norm" id="well"> idle </p> 
 <p class="norm">
 <input type="text" id="tlk" value="" /><input type="button" id="send" value="send" />
 </p>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I hope That someone looking for this will find it. It took me a while to get it right